# Eliminação de palavras repetidas usando o Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

É possível eliminar palavras repetidas em um arquivo de texto usando o Notepad++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se seu Notepad++ estiver com o *plugin* TextFX (as versões mais novas costumam vir com ele. Alternativamente você pode adicioná-lo com facilidade usando o *Plugin manager*), e as palavras estiverem em linhas separadas, você pode fazer desta forma:

1. Selecione o texto desejado (ou dê <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> para selecionar tudo), e ordene as palavras com estas duas opções:

   > *Sort ascending* ( colocar em ordem crescente )

   e

   > *Sort outputs only UNIQUE* ( ordenar apenas saidas com UNIQUE / únicas )
2. Selecionadas as duas opções, clique em uma das duas opções logo acima:

   > Sort lines case sensitive ( se quiser diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas )

   OU

   > Sort lines case insensitive (se for para eliminar as repetidas independente do *casing* ).

[image: screenshot]
<sub>Fonte: [Notepad++ remove duplicates, remove blank lines and sort data in one operation](http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2012/05/16/notepad-remove-duplicates-remove-blank-lines-and-sort-data-in-one-operation/)</sub>

Só não se esqueça de desligar o UNIQUE depois de fazer isso, se for usar o TextFX pra ordenar outra coisa ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Perfeito!

Answer (score 2):

Existe a ferramenta de encontrar e também de substituição de palavras que pode de certa forma fazer isso.

Clicando <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, ele abrirá uma janela com várias opões:

```
Find | Replace | Find in Files | Mark
```

Clicando na *tab* `Replace`, você poderá adicionar a palavra que quer encontrar e pelo o quê que quer substituir, se é por outra palavra ou deixar em branco se quiser que ela seja removida. Poderá substituir uma ou todas palavras no documento atual, ou em todos os documentos/abas em aberto no Notepad++ como pode ver nas opções dos botões situados do lado direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> ### Update
>
> Reparei que ao deixar a opção **"Replace with"** em branco, ele vai substituir por um espaço em branco como resultado final.
> Para resolver esse problema apenas basta fazer uma nova substituição mas desta vez no **"Find what"** colocaremos 2 espaços e no **"Replace with"** colocaremos apenas um espaço para fixar este problema.

Comment: @Chun Muito obrigado pela dica tbm!

Comment: esta resposta não responde a pergunta feita

Comment: @tetri o seu comentário intriga-me. Poderia me dizer na sua perspectiva como é que a minha resposta não responde [à pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112800/11886) feita pelo OP? Estou apenas curioso.